# can i apply delete on this pointer inside a member function?

Tags: c++, dynamic-allocation, static-allocation

As I understand if the member function has been called using pointer to an object which is allocated dynamically, the object would get delete. But if the member function has been called using the object, which is allocated statically, then what will happen ?

```
class sample
{
    int i;
  public:
    void func()
    {
        delete this;
    }
};

void main()
{
    sample *s = new sample;

    s->fun();
    sample s1;
    s1.fun();
}
```

Comment: Provide an example of both maybe?

Comment: Should depend on the heap management, you will most certainly get an error trying to free an invalid block.

Comment: What were your results when you tried it?

Comment: curious why you want the member function to delete the object.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting a pointer inside a member function is OK, as long as you know how that pointer has been allocated. There is no portable way of knowing that from just a pointer alone.

If a function is passed a pointer that has not been allocated dynamically, and the function calls `delete` on that pointer, it is undefined behavior. Moreover, even pointers to dynamic objects allocated as arrays cannot be freed with the regular `delete` operator: you must use `delete[]` on them. A simple rule is that when you do not know the origin of a pointer, you do not call `delete` on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can only use `delete` if the object was allocated using `new`. Simple as that. Therefore the first example you gave is legal, the second is not. The second case is likely to crash, or worse, cause heap corruption and crash at a seemingly random memory allocation somewhere far removed from the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you call delete this inside any member function of object which is statically allocated , then calling delete this will crash at runtime . Because when this object will go out of scope , compiler will automatically call destructor , which will try to delete object which no longer exists.